# Is it grammatical/idiomatic to say "Thursday night" instead of "On Thursday night"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Example:

> On Tuesday night, I went to the see doctor.
>
> On Wednesday night, I visited my uncle's farm.
>
> **Thursday night, I stayed at home**.

I saw some people using this structure on [Google Books](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22Thursday%20night,%20I%22&tbm=bks&ei=cRYhW9W4E4a80ASgpLugCg&start=10&sa=N&biw=1855&bih=933&dpr=1). However, I'm still not sure if it's grammatical/idiomatic to omit the "on."

Comment: The preposition ***on*** is optional in your contexts - as it would be if you hadn't "fronted" the adverbial clause. *I went out Friday night* is idiomatically fine in normal speech (but ***on*** would normally be included in more "formal" contexts).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the language rules of English, "*night*" is a noun.

"*Thursday night*" is **still** a noun.

Nouns can't explain the actions of verbs, but adverbs can.

What you need to make it an adverb is to add the preposition "*on*".

> I stayed at home. **When**? **On** Thursday night.

You can't normally answer that question with just "Thursday night".

So I'd assume it to be grammatically **incorrect**.

Comment: … except that just *Thursday night* would be the most natural thing to say in conversation, much the same as *last night I stayed home* or *yesterday morning I stayed home*.